# Button not Submitting the message in Database

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am Creatng a simple Flask app which stores just a single text field, On a single web page, and on which the user should see a form with the "message" field. Below the form should be a list of existing messages in the database. When user types something in the "message" field and submits the form, the "message" should be saved to a table in SQLite. AND After the message is saved, user should come back to the page with the form and message list.

I am stuck at a POINT I am not being able to SUBMIT the message
My page do retrieve messages from the database which is already stored in the database while I created it.

Please Can SOMEONE guide me codes to SUBMIT the message filled in the form.

My Connection code is:

```
@app.route('/message')
def message():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select msg_msg from msg')
    message = [dict(msg_msg=row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('message.html', message=message)

@app.route('/message', methods=['GET'])
def button():  
    if request.GET.get('Save').strip():
        new = request.GET.get('input_msg').strip()
        g.db = connect_db()
        cur = g.db.execute("INSERT INTO msg (msg_msg) VALUES (?)", (new))
        new_id = c.lastrowid

        g.db.commit()
        g.db.close()

        return '<p>The new input_msg was inserted into the database, the ID is %s</p>' % new_id
    else:
        return render_template('message.html')
```

AND the html code for the page is

```
{% extends "template.html "%}
{% block content %}

    <h2>You are in the Message Page</h2>
    <br/>
    <p><h4>In this page, You can view the Existing Messages and can also Submit your own message.</h4></p>
<br/><br/>

<h3>Enter Your Message:</h3><br/>

<form action="/message" methods='GET'>
<dl>
    <dt>Message:
    <dd><input type="text" name="input_msg" maxlength=80   style="width:300px">*Maximum Length = 80
</dl>
<input type=submit value="Save">

</form>

<h3>The Existing Messages:</h3>
{% for item in message %}
Msg_ID: <B>"{{ item.msg_id }}"</B><br/>Message: {{ item.msg_msg }} <br/><br/>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: GET is implied if I remember correctly. I suggest visiting flask.pocoo.org and looking at the docs because your dispatching isn’t standard. You should handle all get requests in the default @app.route() function

Answer (score 0):

You need use POST to handle the receiving data.

```
@app.route('/message', methods=['GET','POST'])
if request.method='POST':
    new = request.form['input_msg'].strip()
    ...
    return redirect(url_for('XXXX'))
else:
    ...
    return render_template('message.html')
```

de
and your message.html:

```
<form action='/message' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="input_msg" maxlength=80   style="width:300px">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I suggest that you need read the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) because your code is not standard.